# Прямая авторизация в вк

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Осуществляю прямую авторизация в вк,clientId и clientSecret получил из вк приложения,путем декомпилирования.
Запрос вот такой
json_decode(file_get_contents("https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=".$clientId."&client_secret".$clientSecret."&username=test@mail.ru&password=dfdfdf&scope=notify,friends,photos,audio,video,stories,pages,menu,wallmenu,status,notes,messages,wall,ads,docs,groups,notifications,stats,email,leads,phone"), true);

Ответ приходит вот такой
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized in /home/
В чем может быть проблема.Спасибо.

Comment: у вас не везде стоит знак `=` для переменных `"&client_secret".$clientSecret."`, а должно было быть так `"&client_secret=".$clientSecret."`

Comment: Я исправил,но все равно не идет,та же самая ошибка